# Why response not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpresponse

```
var http = require('http');
function foo(req,res){
   res.writeHead(200);
   res.write('Hello,world!');
   res.end('okay');
}
var app = http.createServer();
app.listen(2000);
console.log('Listening on 2000...');
```

Hello. I am learning node.js now,and I have a problem,please help me.
When I operate this code with command,everything is ok.It gives me back 'Listening on 2000...'.But when I work with browser it is loading every time.
Then I operated 'foo' function in command it returned me 
'cannot read property writeHead'
'cannot read property write'
'cannot read property end'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is listening to requests, but it doesn't know what to do once it receives any, because your `http.createServer()` function is not being passed a callback. You defined a callback called `foo` but you aren't using it. Just pass it to `createServer` and your server will respond when you go to `localhost:2000`.

```
var app = http.createServer(foo);
```

[Read more about the Node HTTP module here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).